# Android - VideoView - Views disappear when I go fullscreen

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-fullscreen

When I play a video on a VideoView, all my views on top of it disappear. I am in fullscreen mode.

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

If I remove the fullscreen mode or if I pause the video, all my views are visible. Even if a Toast is visible, my view are visible while the toast is visible.

I am on a Android 4.4.4.

I already tried to create a FrameLayout including all foreground views and bring it to front when I start to play the video.

```
bgVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.setLooping(true);
                        bgVideoView.start();
                        foregroundLayout.bringToFront();
                    }
                });
```

I also tried `bgVideoView.setZOrderOnTop(false)`

My XML is like

```
<FrameLayout>
    <VideoView/>
    <FrameLayout of my foreground views/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around. I just had to activate an option in Developer settings called "Disable HW overlays".